# CXF project undefined element declaration 'xs:schema'

Tags: java, .net, web-services, wsdl, cxf

I am completely new to web service stuff.

I’m a greenhand in CXF with Spring Boot project. After configuring all the projects, I try to use .Net webService inhttp://ws.webxml.com.cn/WebServices/WeatherWS.asmx?wsdl. But I get an error
`undefined element declaration 'xs:schema'`

After a lot google searching, I know that I can place the source xml file and use wsdl2java to put weatherService class in my project. However, I think it breaks my identity as a client and is a repetitive work. Is there any other way for me to handle the problem by using a maven plugin or CXF itself codes?

Any help regarding this would be really helpful
Thanks of all